# Can't exit MySQL with quit ):

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, exit

It now shows:
`mysql>`
and then, I type quit and hit enter and in the next line, it just shows `mysql>` again ): I also tried ctrl+c. I'm on Linux.

Oh exit worked. But like I swear I tried it before and it didn't work!

Comment: Are you sure you hadn't had a previous command not closed correctly. Example: select * from `mytable; (notice tick mark is not closed around mytable). If a tick mark or quote is not closed then when you press enter it will open up a new line waiting for you to finish the command.

Answer (score 2):

The method to quit the interactive MySQL shell is `\q` as per [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html).

`exit` on its own will work, but if you were in the middle of a SQL statement it won't, so like:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM
    -> exit
```

This is presumed to be a table name. `\q` will work instead.

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows**, I could exit **MySQL** with **"exit" or "quit" commands below**:

```
mysql> quit
Bye
```

```
mysql> exit
Bye
```