# unable to stop mysql server on macos terminal after log on as root user

Tags: mysql, macos

i am using a macos to run mysql on the terminal.

what i usually do is:

1. mysql.server start
2. mysql -u root -p

then mysql is okay to be used, for creating database, tables and etc.

but when i want to shut down mysql server. it will give me error message that my syntax is wrong.

mysql.server stop

May i ask if anyone has a similar issue before?

Thank You

I will terminate the terminal then type

mysql.server stop

and it will shut down successfully.

i am hoping i dont need to keep terminating my terminal before i can shut down mysql server.

Comment: If you are at a mysql prompt you must exit the mysql interactive shell first. Then you are back to a "normal" command line prompt on your system, where you can enter system commands (such as stopping services).  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62720074/cant-exit-mysql-with-quit

Answer (score 0):

`mysql.server stop` will only work from shell.

If you started the command line client `mysql` and you want to stop the server, either use the SQL command

`SHUTDOWN`

to shutdown your MySQL server (this requires shutdown privilege). Or execute system shell command with `\!`:

`\! mysql.server stop`.